# Color edges in Neo4j graph using PHP

Tags: php, colors, neo4j, edges, alchemy.js

The objective of my application is to secure the data using a `Neo4j` graph and `PHP`. I have some users, each one has access to a specific folder. For example:

- **Yannick** has access to **Folder1**
- **Julie** has access to **Folder2**
- If oneday, **Yannick** got access to **Folder2** I have to get the edge between them in *red* color.

I'm using [alchemy.min.js](http://cdn.graphalchemist.com/alchemy.min.js) javascript to color a new node. I used a cluster property. But I didn't find the way to color just the newly added edge. In our example I want to color the edge between `__Yannick__` and `__Folder2__` in `_red_`, and then both nodes in `_green_`.

Comment: Can you show us some of the code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not knowledgable on Alchemy specifically, but I would think it would need a edge property to be able to change the color.  You could either put a createDate property on the edge when Yannik receives access, then have alchemy style based on age of createDate (e.g. < 1 day = red)